# JAVA_HOME variable error on cordova android build

Tags: cordova, ngcordova, phonegap

[image: error screenshot]

but when I execute

```
javac -version
```

showing this result

```
javac 1.8.0_131
```

how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove /bin at the end of your JAVA_HOME path